# Getting checkboxes status in case of dynamic list in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, loops, angular, angular-ngmodel

this has been baffling me all the day ; I'm working on an `Angular2` app, I have a list of questions with a `checkbox` attached to each single question, it looks like this [image] The problem is that list is incremented dynamically, so once I add a question it will show up as it illustrated using `ngFor` , here is the code :

```
 <li *ngFor="#qt of listQuestion">
                                
               <span class="md-card-list-item-date">20 Jul</span>
               <div class="md-card-list-item-select">
               <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="theCheckbox" (Change)="addQues($event)"/>  </div>

               <div class="md-card-list-item-subject">
                     <span>{{qt.wordingQ}}</span>
                                </div>
 </li>
```

Where the `wordingQ` is the parameter of the `Question` Object that contains the question wording. So for every added question it will create an `ngModel` which if assigned to **the same variable** (`theCheckbox`) and here the problem occured because when i want to check a question , all the other questions will be checked and vice versa, thus i cannot check the status of every question independently since it is a dynamic list not a static one . Can you guys help me i'm new to `Angular2` how can i create a unique `ngModel` -maybe- for each question or is there any relative solution?
Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating a component for each question. Then every question will have its own scope where you can add connect a model to the checkbox for each question.

```
<li *ngFor="#qt of listQuestion">
  <question [question]="qt"></question>
</li>
```

question.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'question',
  template: ’
           <span class="md-card-list-item-date">20 Jul</span>
           <div class="md-card-list-item-select">
           <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="theCheckbox" (Change)="addQues($event)"/>  </div>
           <div class="md-card-list-item-subject">
             <span>{{question.wordingQ}}</span>
           </div>’
})

export class QuestionComponent {
  @Input() question:any;
  theCheckbox: boolean;
}
```

Comment: a Good idea but it doesn't work since i have already a component for each question ..